# contents of page reload when any user post data in database in php

Tags: php

I have developing messenger in php. In my application in need to reload the content of div in a page while any user post their comments on database of server.
  Please kindly help me...
Thanks in Advance 
Mayan Alagar.

Answer (score 1):

Here a couple of questions/answers that might give you some informations, to start with :

- [Comet & PHP: How to use Comet with a PHP Chat System ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190744/comet-php-how-to-use-comet-with-a-php-chat-system)
- [Using comet with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php)
- [Implementing PHP chat in members site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695944/implementing-php-chat-in-members-site)
- [Ajax polling.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499/ajax-polling)
- [How to make a chat room script with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772471/how-to-make-a-chat-room-script-with-php)

Basically, you'll have to put some long-polling mecanism *(search for "comet")*, to be able to send notifications and new informations from the server to the browser -- while things are generally going the other way arround.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) (or reverse AJAX or push AJAX)